# How do I set a group of toggles to be mutually exclusive in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
@State private var isOn1 = false
@State private var isOn2 = false

var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        Toggle("switch1",isOn:$isOn1)
        Toggle("switch2",isOn:$isOn2)
    }
```

Here is what I have so far. Is there a way for me to add an if statement when activating a toggle that all the other toggles will be off. Or is there anyway to change the states of the toggles when activating one. Any answers are appreciated thank you!

Comment: Is it reasonable to just use one `bool`?

Comment: What If I want 9 toggles to be mutually exclusive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `isOn2` as a `Binding`. You can create a `Binding` by passing in a closure for its getter and another one for its setter. For your `isOn2` `Binding` you'll simply need to return the negated value of `isOn1` and in its setter, you'll set `isOn1` to the negated value passed in to the setter.

```
struct ToggleView: View {
    @State private var isOn1 = false

    var body: some View {
        let isOn2 = Binding<Bool>(
            get: { !self.isOn1 },
            set: { self.isOn1 = !$0 }
        )
        return ScrollView{
            Toggle("switch1",isOn: $isOn1)
            Toggle("switch2",isOn: isOn2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Say I have 7 toggles and I only want one to be selected would this method still be efficient?

Comment: @IMKt if you need more than 2 toggles, an `Array` based approach would be easier to use as shown in Asperi's answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is some alternate approach, which does not require to hardcode interdependently all bindings, but instead use shared storage of bools:

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoExclusiveToggles: View {
    @State var flags = Array(repeating: false, count: 9)
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(flags.indices) { i in
                ToggleItem(storage: self.$flags, tag: i, label: "Switch \(i+1)")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleItem: View {
    @Binding var storage: [Bool]
    var tag: Int
    var label: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        let isOn = Binding (get: { self.storage[self.tag] },
            set: { value in
                withAnimation {
                    self.storage = self.storage.enumerated().map { $0.0 == self.tag }
                }
            })
        return Toggle(label, isOn: isOn)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can improve it with an enum

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution and more practical example. Keep track of the active selection and create a binding that checks and sets the active selection

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
  var name: String
  let id: UUID = .init()
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var items: [Item] = [Item(name: "Item 1"),
                              Item(name: "Item 2"),
                              Item(name: "Item 3")]

  @State var activeItem: Item?

  var body: some View {
    List(items) { item in
      HStack {
        Text(item.name)
        let isOn = Binding<Bool>(get: { activeItem == item },
                                 set: { _ in activeItem = item })
        Toggle("", isOn: isOn)
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      activeItem = items[0]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).