# Only one switch is on

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, switch-statement, rx-swift

I'm struggle with following challenge. I created table view with custom cell that contains switch. I wanna only one switch can be on i.e, for instance after launch I switched on 3rd switched and then I switched on 7th switch and thus the 3rd one is switched off and so on. I use rx + protocols for cell and don't understand all the way how to determine which switch was toggled. Previously I was going to use filter or map to look up in dataSource array which switch is on and somehow handle this, but now I messed up with it. I'm not sure it's possible without using table view delegate methods. Thanks a lot, hope someone could explain where I am wrong.

//My cell looks like this: [image]

// CellViewModel implementation

```
    import Foundation
    import RxSwift

protocol ViewModelProtocol {
    var bag:DisposeBag {get set}

    func dispose()
}

class ViewModel:ViewModelProtocol {
    var bag = DisposeBag()

    func dispose() {
        self.bag = DisposeBag()
    }
}


protocol CellViewModelProtocol:ViewModelProtocol {
    var isSwitchOn:BehaviorSubject<Bool> {get set}
}

class CellVM:ViewModel, CellViewModelProtocol {
    var isSwitchOn: BehaviorSubject<BooleanLiteralType> = BehaviorSubject(value: false)

    let internalBag = DisposeBag()

    override init() {

    }

}
```

//My Cell implementation

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class Cell:UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "cell"

    @IBOutlet weak var stateSwitch:UISwitch!

    var vm:CellViewModelProtocol? {
        didSet {
            oldValue?.dispose()
            self.bindUI()
        }
    }

    var currentTag:Int?

    var bag = DisposeBag()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.bindUI()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.bag = DisposeBag()
    }


    private func bindUI() {
        guard let vm = self.vm else { return }

        self.stateSwitch.rx.controlEvent(.valueChanged).withLatestFrom(self.stateSwitch.rx.value).observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance).bind(to: vm.isSwitchOn).disposed(by: vm.bag)

    }
}
```

//TableViewController implementation

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var dataSource:[CellViewModelProtocol] = []

    var vm = TableViewControllerVM()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self.bindUI()
    }

    private func bindUI() {
        vm.dataSource.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance).bind { [weak self] (dataSource) in
            self?.dataSource = dataSource
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }.disposed(by: vm.bag)
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell

        if cell.vm == nil {
            cell.vm = CellVM()
        }

        return cell
    }

}

class TableViewControllerVM:ViewModel {

    var dataSource:BehaviorSubject<[CellViewModelProtocol]> = BehaviorSubject(value: [])

    let internalBag = DisposeBag()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        dataSource.onNext(createDataSourceOf(size: 7))
        self.handleState()
    }

    private func createDataSourceOf(size:Int) -> [CellViewModelProtocol] {
        var arr:[CellViewModelProtocol] = []
        for _ in 0..<size {
            let cell = CellVM()
            arr.append(cell)
        }
        return arr
    }

    private func handleState() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61825818/4667835) answer for the same problem, just using SwiftUI and Combine. You should be able to use the same idea, just translate it into RxSwift and UIKit.

Comment: thanks a lot @DávidPásztor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you:

```swift
extension TableViewController {
    // called from viewDidLoad
    func bind() {
        let cells = (0..<7).map { _ in UUID() } // each cell needs an ID
        let active = ReplaySubject<UUID>.create(bufferSize: 1) // tracks which is the currently active cell by ID

        Observable.just(cells) // wrap the array in an Observable
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: Cell.self)) { _, element, cell in
                // this subscription causes the inactive cells to turn off
                active
                    .map { $0 == element }
                    .bind(to: cell.toggleSwitch.rx.isOn)
                    .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)

                // this subscription watches for when a cell is set to on.
                cell.toggleSwitch.rx.isOn
                    .filter { $0 }
                    .map { _ in element }
                    .bind(to: active)
                    .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar UI,so tested locally and it works.But not very neat code.

ProfileCellViewModel

```
struct ProfileCellViewModel {

    // IMPORTANT!!!
    var bibindRelay: BehaviorRelay<Bool>?
}
```

ProfileCell

```
final class ProfileCell: TableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: Label!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerLabel: Label!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLabel: Label!

    @IBOutlet weak var onSwitch: Switch!

    public var vm: ProfileCellViewModel? {
        didSet {


            // IMPORTANT!!!
            if let behaviorRelay = vm?.bibindRelay {
                (onSwitch.rx.controlProperty(editingEvents: .valueChanged,
                                             getter: { $0.isOn }) { $0.isOn = $1 } <-> behaviorRelay)
                    .disposed(by: self.rx.reuseBag)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

ProfileViewModel

```
final class ProfileViewModel: ViewModel, ViewModelType {

    struct Input {
        let loadUserProfileStarted: BehaviorRelay<Void>
    }

    struct Output {
        let userItems: BehaviorRelay<[ProfileCellViewModel]>
        let chatRelay: BehaviorRelay<Bool>
        let callRelay: BehaviorRelay<Bool>
    }

    let input = Input(loadUserProfileStarted: BehaviorRelay<Void>(value: ()))
    let output = Output(userItems: BehaviorRelay<[ProfileCellViewModel]>(value: []),
                        chatRelay: BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false),
                        callRelay: BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value:false))

    override init() {
        super.init()


        // IMPORTANT!!!
        Observable.combineLatest(output.chatRelay,output.callRelay).pairwise().map { (arg0) -> Int in

            let (pre, curr) = arg0

            let preFlag = [pre.0,pre.1].filter { $0 == true }.count == 1
            let currFlag = [curr.0,curr.1].filter { $0 == true }.count == 2

            if preFlag && currFlag {
                return [pre.0,pre.1].firstIndex(of: true) ?? 0
            }

            return -1

        }.filter {$0 >= 0}.subscribe(onNext: { (value) in

            [self.output.chatRelay,self.output.callRelay][value].accept(false)

        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)



    }

    private func createProfileCellItems(user: User) -> [ProfileCellViewModel] {


        // IMPORTANT!!!
        let chatCellViewModel = ProfileCellViewModel(topText: nil,
                                       centerText: R.string.i18n.chat(),
                                       bottomText: nil,
                                       switchStatus: true,
                                       bibindRelay: output.chatRelay)

        // IMPORTANT!!!
        let callCellViewModel = ProfileCellViewModel(topText: nil,
                                       centerText: R.string.i18n.call(),
                                       bottomText: nil,
                                       switchStatus: true,
                                       bibindRelay: output.callRelay)

        return [roleCellViewModel,
                teamCellViewModel,
                statusCellViewModel,
                sinceCellViewModel,
                chatCellViewModel,
                callCellViewModel]
    }
}
```

I mark the codes you should pay attention to with `// IMPORTANT!!!`

Comment: you could have removed the code that is irrelevant to the answer and that would have made it much more clear...

Comment: @DanielT. would like to show more context at the first place,I can remove irrelevant codes later.